# How to add emoticons in UITextView while editing

Tags: uitextview, emoticons, viber

I am developing xmpp-client app. One of the features is sending smiles and user should have ability to edit its like usuall text. Emoticons editing in Viber App is best example of what i want to implement.

I already tried three ways to solve problem:

I create emoticon like usual UIImageView and place it as a subview on UITextView using current caret rect. I use 5 whitespaces as a text placeholder in text view. There are two problems: with placing emoticons on new line when inserting text in the middle(printing whitespace not make caret move to new line); when user placing caret using magnify glass, he can move caret through emoticon(through 5 whitespaces), as delegate method not called during this process.

I have tried EGOTextView. There are problems with caret position and resizing when new line should be added. And there are some rendering artifacts when using it one line size.

I also have tried using UIWebView. But there were great problems with resizing based on text size and other artifacts with speed of response when becoming first responder.
May be some one could give me advice of really working solution?

Any suggestion please?

Thanks!